# Calling ggsave inside function

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot data derived from a collection of CSV files, but I seem to be having some trouble with using ggplot and ggsave from within a function. Despite having defined a dataframe earlier in the function, ggsave complains with the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dataframe' not found  
Calls: process ... sapply -> lapply -> eval.quoted -> lapply -> FUN ->
eval
```

I have found some forums referring to oddities in R scoping, but I can't see how ggplot is failing to look up a variable defined a couple lines before.

function code is:

```
process <- function(path) {
    ...
    byhour <-table(audit$method, audit$hour)

    dataframe <- data.frame(byhour)
    dataframe$time <- strptime(dataframe$Var2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    basename <- file_path_sans_ext(path)
    plotname <- paste0(basename, ".jpg")

    plot <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(dataframe$time, Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_datetime()
    ggsave(plot, file=plotname)
}
```

Comment: I don't think taht the error you mention is  in relation with `ggsave`. can you please add the code you used to get such error.

Comment: Can't help you without the code.  Please try replacing ggsave with print( of the ggplot.

Comment: I think it is a `ggplot2/qplot` error which can't find one the aes. I guess you try to do something like `lapply(...,function(dataframe)qplot(x=dataframe[,1], data=dataframe,...)` and for some reason you can't create `dataframe` vraiable.

Comment: try replacing `aes(dataframe$time, Freq)` with `aes(time,Freq)`

Comment: The lesson here is you should never be using the `$` operator inside of `aes()`.

Comment: yep, removing dataframe from aes() did the trick. I'm a n00b, can you explain why it is so in an answer?